# Sharepoint 2010 user permission issues

Tags: 2010, permissions, user-accounts

In Sharepoint 2010 (on prem deployment), I have created a publishing page which contains a custom list and a few views.

I have broken permissions inheritance for this page. There are three users within one permissions group (full control).

One of the users within the said group is unable to create or modify list views. I have tested the permissions on a couple of different accounts with no problems and can edit/create views.

I have already tried to reset the permissions for this user by deleting from this group and giving full control access directly. Furthermore, I have also tried assigning the user to another permission group (full control). This also had no effect.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Multiple domains?  User's browser and version?

Comment: Single domain, user experiencing the issue has tried on the latest version of FF and IE8+. Thanks

Comment: Compatibility Mode on or off?

Comment: Have already tried both with the user, no luck

Comment: Can the user edit the list view settings if provided the URL directly instead of using the ribbon.  Or perhaps through the list settings, modify/create view.

Comment: User is able to see the list view settings when given direct URL. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permissions on the list itself, by the sounds of things, the list may have different permissions to the page

Comment: Have checked the permissions on the list and it is inheriting from its parent which is the page. Thanks

Comment: A list cannot inherit from a page.  A page is an item in a library.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen an issue with a user having full control on a subsite, but no permission on the top level site.  Some of the system pages and functionality is reliant on contents of system lists/libraries at the root.  Try granting your group read access at the root site for the collection.